# How to mark a message as "in progress" so other workers don't work on it

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

I'm attempting to use a pull queue to create a queue of image processing tasks that could take longer that the acktimeout limit of 10 minutes. I'm using node.js api and I'm wondering how I could have a worker grab a message off the pull queue, mark it as in progress so no other workers attempt to grab it, do its work and acknowledge the message after the processing is done. This processing could take up to an hour per worker. If an exception occurs, I'd like to remove the "in progress" status and allow other workers to pick up this message and attempt to work on it.

I was hoping there was something in pubsub that would allow me to do this. My alternative is to, before processing, store an entity (inProgressMessage) with the message id, ack id, status=pending, timestamp=now() into datastore, have the worker immediately return the ackid after receiving the message (this will allow other workers to attempt other messages), then the worker can work on the lengthy task. If successful, mark the entity status as complete, if failed in a non permanent way, requeue the task into pubsub, if failed in a permanent way that won't allow reqeueing, I can have  cron that checks datastore for pending tasks older than several hours and have them either be deleted or requeued.

My alternative feels like i'm re-implementing alot of what pub sub is supposed to help with.

Let me know if you can think of a better way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To take longer than the ack deadline to process a message, you'll want to use [modifyAckDeadline](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/modifyAckDeadline). You can extend the deadline as many times as you need up to 10 minutes per call. Your workflow would be as follows:

1. Pull the message.
2. Start to process the message.
3. While you are not done with the message, if you are close to the 10 minute ack deadline, call modifyAckDeadline to extend the deadline.
4. Once done processing the message, ack it.

Please note that calling modifyAckDeadline does not *guarantee* that the message won't be delivered to another task. In certain circumstances like server restarts, the message may end up being delivered to another of your subscribers. However, in most normal circumstances, as long as you call modifyAckDeadline before the current ack deadline, you can prevent a message's redelivered as long as necessary.

Comment: Thanks so much, that sounds like a great solution!

Comment: The [Python doc](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/blob/8616c45291e999ad83b8b45fe16d990f73cbed0f/pubsub/google/cloud/pubsub_v1/subscriber/message.py#L233-L236) at least says `modify_ack_deadline` doesn't *extend* the deadline, it *sets* it. Otherwise, this would have been a good solution for my arbitrary-length processes.

Comment: The reason it says that is because it can be used to shrink the deadline, too. But the same method can be used to extend the deadline. If you `modify_ack_deadline` to 60 seconds, then the subscriber will hold a lease on the message fom now + 60 seconds. Likewise, if you `modify_ack_deadline` to 0 seconds, then the subscriber will hold a lease on the message for now + 0 seconds, effectively nacking the message and redelivering it.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - the pydoc indeed says `from right now`.

Comment: The docs will hopefully get [even better](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-python/pull/4822).

Answer (score 0):

When creating a topic (only), you can configure the acknowledge time to be whatever up to **10 minutes** (https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/subscriber). Once a message has been pulled from the queue, no other worker (of the same subscriber) will be able to take it for processing, unless the ack ttl was reached, and then the message is automatically returned to queue.

Since you need a longer period, you will have to implement something on your own, or seek another queuing solution. I think the design you suggested is fairly simple to implement, and is not really a re-implementation of what pubsub does.